# eclipse - put current line to top of screen/editor window?

Tags: eclipse, navigation

How to put current line at the top of screen/editor window/viewport? 
I looking for something exactly similar to that is achieved in vim using `Shift` + `H` or `z<return>`.

Do anyone know about such a config? It would be a great navigating tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'Recenter' command to do this. Running this command cycles through moving the cursor line to the center line, then the top line, then the bottom line.

By default this command is not bound to a key so you need to open Preferences > General > Keys. Find Recenter and add a key binding.

Comment: +1 greg This helps. I see the current line is being put to center of the screen, but it doesn't cycle to center-top-bottom. Is there any other config, i tried searching the `Keys`, but didn't find anything relevant. Note. I am using eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Anyways, that is really helpful. :)

Comment: For me the first key press centers, pressing again moves to the top, pressing again moves to the bottom. I am on Eclipse Luna. The file has to be long enough to fill the window when move to top is used.

Comment: i'm using kepler, it only centers the line, does not cycle through top/bottom/center.